# symfony2: setting the value of a form field outside the form, inside a controller action

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, image-upload

I need to set the value of a symfony2 form element.
I use a doctrine2 entity, a **Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType** and the createForm() method inside my Controllers Action.

```
$saleDataForm = $this->createForm(new SaleType(), $sale);
```

Now, how do i get an element from that form, and how can i set it's value?
I want to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$saleDataForm->get('image')->setValue('someimapge.jpg');
```

FYI: I need to do this to render the field correctly (using [this approach](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html), my *image* field is always empty and i need to set it to the content of *imagePath* to present a preview of an uploaded image)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**For a more exact answer you should include the entities you use in this form so we can see the getters and setters. But based on your question this should work:**
Inside the controller do this:

```
$saleDataForm->getData()->getImage()->setValue('someimage.jpg');
$form->setData($form->getData());
```

This is if the form is already created so:

```
$saleDataForm = $this->createForm(new SaleType(), $sale);
$saleDataForm->getData()->getImage()->setValue('someimage.jpg');
$form->setData($form->getData());
```

To get the data use this:

```
$saleDataForm->getData()->getImage()->getValue();
```

Comment: This works for mapped fields only. How do you do it for non-mapped ?

Answer (score 5):

thanks MatsRietdijk, you helped me, but I had to change code to this

```
$form = $this->createForm(new SaleType(), $sale);
$form->getData()->setImage('someimage.jpg');
$form->setData($form->getData());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you try fill file upload field - it's wrong idea. Ask yourself: what data should be there? If an user upload an image, then in this field will be a path to the image on his local system. But then after file is uploaded you change its name and location, so you don't need info about this path and you just don't keep it.

The appropriate way should be left empty upload field below (or above, or wherever you have it ;) ) image. Then after form is submitted and if the field is not empty you should change edited image.