# How to change form field value in symfony 2

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I have a form like below:

```php
class ItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // ...
            ->add('tags','text',array(
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array('name' => 'tags'),
                'mapped' => false))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\ItemBundle\Entity\Item',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }
}
```

My edit action

```php
public function editAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('MyBundleItemBundle:Item')->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(new ItemType(), $entity);
    //$form->get('tags')->setValue('test text');
    // ^- this is what i would like to do -^
    // ...
}
```

While I am editing an item, How can I change form field value inside controller before rendering it?

Comment: You can do in your case:
$form->get('fieldName')->setData('my_value');
This works also for Symfony 3.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use `setData()` to set data on form fields in Symfony, like this:

```php
$form = $formBuilder->getForm();

$form->get('firstname')->setData('John');
```

Comment: Could you please provide me an example?

Comment: I just want to say that this method is working for me when I do not provide entity to form, otherwise this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249485/symfony2-setting-the-value-of-a-form-field-outside-the-form-inside-a-controlle/21039877#21039877

Comment: This didn't work for me, but simply doing $form->setData(array('field'=>'value')) works.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it if you're running a modern version of Symfony. If this doesn't work for you, upgrade or figure out why it's not working.

Comment: @Acyra setting the value with an associative array doesn't work for me on SF4.4 but setting the values individually does and I can't work out why

Answer (score 3):

You can change tags value in the controller:

```
$request = $this->get('request');
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') 
{
    $form->bind($request);
    if $form->isValid())
    {
        $entity->setTags('test');
        //persist ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `$form-bind()` is obsolete since Symfony 2.3 and is expected to be removed in 3.0. One should use `$form->handleRequest($request)` instead in the newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ...
            ->add('tags','text',array(
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array('name' => 'tags','value'=>'newvalue'),
                'mapped' => false))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\ItemBundle\Entity\Item',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to change it inside controller action

Comment: where is the controller action?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to set the value is to use form options:

```
class ItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // ...
            ->add('tags','text',array(
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array('name' => 'tags'),
                'mapped' => false,
                'data' => $options['tags_value'],
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\ItemBundle\Entity\Item',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'tags_value' => 'default value if you want',
        ));
    }
```

And then in controller:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('MyBundleItemBundle:Item')->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(new ItemType(), $entity, ['tags_value' => 'test text']);
}
```