# Setting form data manually, with viewData value and not ModelData

Tags: forms, view, model, entity, symfony

Going crazy, with Symfony 3.

The question is: *What would be the proper way to set a value into a Symfony form, with simply setting the viewData instead of the modelData, and the form would take care of the transformation?*

...with a small catch: without the usual form/request creation and handling. :)

Something like (presuming we're setting a field which is a DateTime in the DB):

```
$form = $this->createForm(ProperForm::class, $existingData);
$form->setPlainScreenFormattedData('myDateField', '11/29/2016');
```

which would convert the given date into a proper \Datetime object and nicely set it in the form?

### Example and explanation:

I'm using a package for inline editing of HTML table data (Tabledit) and kind of have to stay with that package (due to time/space issues). It sends following data (by ajax) to the server:

- name of the form field
- ID of the data in DB
- new value to be persisted to DB

That's all nice and plays well with the saving controller - as long as it works with plain textual data. When you try to change an EntityType, or some Datetime field with it - it breaks. 
And it breaks, because I try to set a plain, for-screen formatted value into either the form or the underlying object of the form.

To prevent the breaking and still have a one-for-all solution, I tried various forms of creating the given form and using, for example:

```
- $form->get($field)->setData($value)
- $form->setData([$field => $value)])
- $form->getData()->AProperFieldSetterName($value)
```

and more (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477572/how-to-change-form-field-value-in-symfony-2)), but none of those work, because basically, all of those are expecting for the $value to be a **modelData** (like it's said [here](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html#method_setData)).

### My reasoning

I would not like to create new data transformers for this - because they are already in, Symfony knows about this form and its underlying object structure.
Also, I would not like to need to change existing solution, and to stop sending individual fields to the controller, for updating.

I could solve this with creating some manual calls to the DB to first fetch the proper hydrated objects for each field, based on given ID (like `$em->getRepository('somerepo')->find($value)` (for entities), or manually creating the Datetimes, and then feeding that to the form) but this all seems non-good and doubling the existing functionality.

Is there a simple way to do this data transformation? It feels like there should be one. Or did I went too far into non-Symfony ways and got lost?

Comment: The proper way?  Don't do it.  The Symfony form works well when used as designed.  Attempts to do the sort of stuff you are trying to do will get you committed.  If you really need to use this html table editor then write your own handler to deal with the posted data.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad. I was kind of expecting a similar answer. Though, it still seems strange that there is no **simple** way to just use already existing functionality, even when not really in Symfony's way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with `\Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface::submit`