# Symfony2 : How to change hidden field value on PRE_SUBMIT

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

This is how the hidden value is added in the `$formBuilder` :

```
->add('depth', 'hidden', array('mapped'=>false, 'data' => 1))
```

I have a function that is fired `ON_PRE_SUBMIT`, at the line below I assumed this field's value would change but that is not the case.

```
$form->get('depth')->setData($depth++); //$depth = $form->get('depth')->getData();
```

I have also tried to do as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249485/symfony2-setting-the-value-of-a-form-field-outside-the-form-inside-a-controlle/21039877#21039877) :

```
$data = $event->getData();
$data['depth'] = $depth++;
$form->setData($data);
```

But nothing changes. I have tried the above codes on other fields and they change the fields values normally. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Set the data on the $event:

```php
$data = $event->getData();
$data['depth'] = $depth + 1;
$event->setData($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing i noticed is that you are using `$depth++` which will assign the value first and then increment it so u will end up assigning the old value. try to change this:

```
$form->get('depth')->setData(++$depth);
```

Can you also try to change the Event to `POST_SUBMIT`, I believe if you use `PRE_SUBMIT` the submitted data will override any data you modify on `PRE_SUBMIT`

Comment: Please explain why this fixes the problem.

Comment: Even though I was very skeptical about pre-increment vs post-increment theories here, I tried this and can confirm that the 'depth' value is still the same.

Comment: I updated my answer, check if my other suggestion solves your issue

Comment: You cannot change the data of a submitted form.
500 Internal Server Error - AlreadySubmittedException

Comment: then your best choice is to use data transformers explained here http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html